# Throw an exception message from server (ASP.Net MVC) and show as a Javascript notification

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, exception, notifications

How can I customize `Exception handling` in the ASP.Net project and get exception message that has been thrown from the server in a global javascript file and show it as an alert of javascript notification?
For example, this is part of your project:

```
    try
    {
        // your code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
```

I need to catch this message in the global javascript file and show it in my notification.
Js file:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            ShowNotification('Exception.Message')
    }
```

I searched a lot on the Internet but I couldn't find a suitable example.

Comment: You need to return the exception message as ViewBag/model property/JSON, then pass it into the client-side function which uses `alert` or `append`. Please provide further details about client-side function name and location (e.g. in external JS file).

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto I put sample js code. I need to catch that exception message here.

Comment: You can try using `ViewBag` first, e.g. `ViewBag.Message = e.Message` and then `ShowNotification('@ViewBag.Message')` on JS side. Or you can create a viewmodel dedicated to store error message and put it like `ShowNotification('@Model.Message')`.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto Could you please share an example or put your code here?

Comment: I want to have one global js file that catch all exception error message. Is it possible?

Comment: As long as the function has string parameter to show the message, it's fine to put it inside an external JS file, but make sure that JS file included in the view. The exception message from server-side code can be returned using `ViewBag` or viewmodel property, depending on your choice.

Comment: I think you suggest something like Ajax. But I need to have my js always listen to exception from server

Comment: Can you leave a sample code or share an url?

Comment: Well, I think you can look for these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644523/trying-to-pass-error-message-from-controller-to-view-without-page-reload-mvc & https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/accessing-view-bag-and-view-data-value-in-external-java-script-file. But if you want to watch possible error messages continuously, that's a different issue.

Comment: No, I want to handle all exception in js file